# How do I enable facebook SessionLoginBehavior my Login Pop up dissapears

Tags: android, firebase, facebook-graph-api, firebase-authentication

This is the initialization

```
mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
            btnSignInFacebook = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button_fb);
            btnSignInFacebook.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
            btnSignInFacebook.getLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
```

I need to enable this so my dialog pop us can stob dissapearing but I am beeing told is unrecognized

```
 btnSignInFacebook.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                progressDialog.show();
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
            }



        });
```

I have the class to enable session login behaviour

```
public enum SessionLoginBehavior {
    /**
     * Specifies that Session should attempt Single Sign On (SSO), and if that
     * does not work fall back to dialog auth. This is the default behavior.
     */
    SSO_WITH_FALLBACK(true, true),

    /**
     * Specifies that Session should only attempt SSO. If SSO fails, then the
     * open or new permissions call fails.
     */
    SSO_ONLY(true, false),

    /**
     * Specifies that SSO should not be attempted, and to only use dialog auth.
     */
    SUPPRESS_SSO(false, true);

    private final boolean allowsKatanaAuth;
    private final boolean allowsWebViewAuth;

    private SessionLoginBehavior(boolean allowsKatanaAuth, boolean allowsWebViewAuth) {
        this.allowsKatanaAuth = allowsKatanaAuth;
        this.allowsWebViewAuth = allowsWebViewAuth;
    }

    boolean allowsKatanaAuth() {
        return allowsKatanaAuth;
    }

    boolean allowsWebViewAuth() {
        return allowsWebViewAuth;
    }
```

I am using 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'